# SQL Server - Parse string with delimiter and 'n' characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that contains a large text string such as:

> some unique name string/another unique name
>   string/string_12345.jpg,some unique name string/another unique name
>   string/string_45765.jpg,some unique name string/another unique name
>   string/string_98765.jpg

The only pattern present is the substrings I need contain exactly 5 digits preceding the file type ".jpg". Each sub-string I need also ends in a ","

I need something that uses the delimiter of .jpg  (it's possible that "." is used elsewhere in the string.)and the 5 indexes before that delimiter. 
Any suggestions or pointers on where to start? The string can be longer and contain dozens of ".jpg" or one.

**Expected Result**

Something like this:

```
     "12345.jpg45765.jpg98765.jpg"
```

The final result would after some more cleanup, it would likely look like the following. However I don't want to complicate the original ask. The above result is fine for my needs at this time.

```
     "12345.jpg - 45765.jpg - 98765.jpg"
```

Comment: This answers your question indirectly, but a much better table structure would be to have one record for each file name. It is really bad to have comma separated values in you database.

Comment: Based on your sample data, what is the expected result?

Comment: add 2 or 3 sample data with expected output here

Comment: Write a CLR user function to do it. SQL isn't the best language for this type of manipulation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131077.aspx

Comment: @JRLambert, I absolutely agree. This data is coming from a customers spreadsheet. Unfortunately I have no control over how it's compiled. I'm basically cleaning it up so it's usable.

Comment: @FelixPamittan the expected result would be a string:  "12345.jpg45765.jpg98765.jpg" from that I have the something more usable.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the five characters before the first `.jpg`, then you can do:

```
select (case when str like '%_____.jpg%'
             then substring(str, charindex('.jpg', str) - 5, 5)
        end) as char5
```

Otherwise, you'll need heavier equipment -- a table-valued UDF to split the string, a recursive CTE, or fancy XML parsing.

Comment: This works but only for the first case where the ".jpg" delimiter is found. I need it to loop through. I'm in the process of working on a for loop using while.  I see you did mention a recursive CTE. So nvm I'll look into that

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea:

```
declare @text varchar(max)='some unique name string/another unique name string/string_12345.jpg,some unique name string/another unique name string/string_45765.jpg,some unique name string/another unique name string/string_98765.jpg'
print @text
declare @new varchar(max)
while (charindex('.jpg',@text))>0
begin
select substring(@text,charindex('.jpg',@text)-5,5)
set @text=SUBSTRING(@text,charindex('.jpg',@text)+5,len(@text))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend a post about tally tables and its benefits on manipulating strings:

http://sql-question.blogspot.com.ar/2012/10/what-is-tally-table-in-sql-server.html

This is how you create a tally or numbers table:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO Numbers
    FROM sys.objects s1       --use sys.columns if you don't get enough rows returned to generate all the numbers you need
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2 --use sys.columns if you don't get enough rows returned to generate all the numbers you need
ALTER TABLE Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_NumbersTest PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)

select count(*) from Numbers
```

I'll come back later and complete this answer with an utilizable script, in the mean time, try to cross join your table with it.